# How to achieve TestNG like feature in Python Selenium or add multiple unit test in one test suite?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, python-unittest, nose

Suppose I have this two nosetest ExampleTest1.py and ExampleTest2.py

```
 ExampleTest1.py
 class ExampleTest1(TestBase):
            """
            """

        def testExampleTest1(self):
            -----
            -----

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import nose
        nose.run()

---------------
ExampleTest2.py
class ExampleTest2(TestBase):
        """
        """

        def testExampleTest2(self):
            -----
            -----

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import nose
        nose.run()
```

Now I want to run such hundreds of test files from a single suite.

I am looking something like TestNG feature like testng.xml below where I can add all my test files which should run one by one

```
 <suite name="Suite1">
      <test name="ExampleTest1">
        <classes>
           <class name="ExampleTest1" />          
        </classes>
      </test>  
      <test name="ExampleTest2">
        <classes>
           <class name="ExampleTest2" />          
        </classes>
      </test>  
    </suite>
```

In case testng.xml like feature is not available in python, then what is other alternative to create test suites and include all my python test there? Thanks

Comment: which unit test framework are you using ? what have you searched so far ?

Comment: I am using nosetests. I have tried a lot to find solution to my above question, but didn't got it yet, so asked it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there may be multiple different reasons why you may want
to construct test suites, I’ll give you several options.

### Just running tests from directory

Let’s say there is `mytests` dir:

```
mytests/
├── test_something_else.py
└── test_thing.py
```

Running all tests from that dir is a easy as

```
$> nosetests mytests/
```

For example, you could put smoke, unit, and integration tests into
different dirs and still be able to run “all tests”:

```
$> nosetests functional/ unit/ other/
```

### Running tests by tag

Nose has
[attribute selector plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html).
With test like this:

```
import unittest

from nose.plugins.attrib import attr


class Thing1Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @attr(platform=("windows", "linux"))
    def test_me(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(1, 0 - 1)

    @attr(platform=("linux", ))
    def test_me_also(self):
        self.assertFalse(2 == 1)
```

You’ll be able to run tests that have particular tag:

```
$> nosetests -a platform=linux tests/

$> nosetests -a platform=windows tests/
```

### Running manually constructed test suite

Finally, `nose.main` supports `suite` argument: if it is passed,
[discovery is not done](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/7c26ad1e6b7d308cafa328ad34736d34028c122a/nose/core.py#L86).
Here I provide you basic example of how to manually construct
test suite and then run it with Nose:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

import nose


def get_cases():
    from test_thing import Thing1Test
    return [Thing1Test]


def get_suite(cases):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for case in cases:
        tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(case)
        suite.addTests(tests)
    return suite


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nose.main(suite=get_suite(get_cases()))
```

As you can see, `nose.main` gets regular `unittest` test suite, constructed
and returned by `get_suite`. The `get_cases` function is where test cases
of your choice are “loaded” (in example above case class is just imported).

If you really need XML, `get_cases` may be the place where you return case
classes that you get from modules (imported via `__import__` or
`importlib.import_module`) which you get from XML file you parsed.
And near `nose.main` call you could use `argparse` to get path to XML file.