# Automatically call another test script from another test script using Appium and Python for IOS

Tags: python, ios, appium

I am using Appium and Python to create some tests, to test the basic UI elements of my app in IOS. I currently have two Python scripts that test two different VC's. I would ideally like to have an individual test script per VC. However, I would really like to be able to call the next test script at the end of the Python script that is currently running.

So far I am calling the next script using the syntax "subprocess.Popen('python test_appium_authCodeRegister.py 1', shell=True)" in the final test in the first VC, however, as I am running the testing in the terminal, it only shows the "7 passed in 107.74 seconds" green text after the first test script, not the second.

Although the second script is currently running after the third (as it is being called in the last test of the first script), the terminal doesn't give me any feedback as to whether the tests passed or not.

Please find my code below.

I have tried putting the function to call the next script at the very bottom of the script without any success as opposed to calling it in its own test method.

```
import subprocess
import pytest
import test_appium_authCodeRegister
import unittest
import os
from random import randint
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):

    app = ('/Users/Brian/Documents/Projects/funtimeapp/build/Release-iphonesimulator/funtimeapp .app')
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities={
            'app': app,
            'platformName': 'iOS',
            'platformVersion': '12.1',
            'deviceName': 'iPhone XR',
            'autoAcceptAlerts': 'true'
        }
    )

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def testDisabledLoginButton(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    loginButton = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('loginButton')
    loginButton.click()
    self.assertTrue(loginButton.is_enabled)
    print loginButton.is_enabled()

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def testInstitutionField(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    institution = "tesco"
    institutionField = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('institutionField')
    institutionField.send_keys(institution)
    institutionField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    self.assertEqual(institutionField.get_attribute("value"), institution)

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def testUsernameField(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    username = "geez1"
    usernameField = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('usernameField')
    usernameField.send_keys(username)
    usernameField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    self.assertEqual(usernameField.get_attribute("value"), username)

@pytest.mark.run(order=4)
def testPasswordField(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    password = "Password1"
    passwordField = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('passwordField')
    passwordField.send_keys(password)
    passwordField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    self.assertEqual(passwordField.get_attribute("value"), password)

@pytest.mark.run(order=5)
def testRegisterButton(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('registerButton').click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    authCodeTextField = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('authTextField')
    self.assertTrue(authCodeTextField.get_attribute('wdVisible'))

@pytest.mark.run(order=6)
def testLogin(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    self.testInstitutionField()
    self.testUsernameField()
    self.testPasswordField()
        self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('loginButton').click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    welcomeView =     self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('welcome')
    self.assertTrue(welcomeView.get_attribute('wdVisible'))

@pytest.mark.run(order=7)    
def testNextScript(self):
    subprocess.Popen('python test_appium_authCodeRegister.py 1', shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginTests)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: For java I am using Testng framework. Since testng framework is not supported in python, you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323248/how-to-achieve-testng-like-feature-in-python-selenium-or-add-multiple-unit-test   Hope this helps you